# GruntJS refuses to work. Task default or every other was not found

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to setup gruntJS on my local machine. These are the steps I have already done:

1. Install nodeJS
2. Download gruntJS in a root folder of project with command:

   - `npm install -g grunt-cli`
3. Download grunt also in a root folder of project with:

   - `npm install grunt`

Also, I have created `Gruntfile.js` and here is content of it:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    min: {
      css: {
        src: 'templates/folder1/css/*.css',
        dest: 'app.min.css'
      }
    },
  });
};
```

And I was expected how this will work and minimize all css files and move it to the root ( because destination specified as root ).

I need to say how I was follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3Sqljpr-Vc

And I really don't know what I do wrong.

Here is how I call grunt and error ( its better to say warning message ) which I get:

```
C:\wamp\www\myProject>grunt min
Warning: Task "min" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install some tasks for use. From your example i would guess you are trying to minify some CSS?

For that i would use the `grunt-contrib-cssmin` task.  To use first install using

```
npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin
```

you will also need to register the task at the bottom of your gruntfile like this `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin')`.

then your gruntfile will look like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
   // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        cssmin: {
            minify: {
                src: ['templates/folder1/css/*.css'],
                dest: 'app.min.css'
            }
        }
    });
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.registerTask('min' ['cssmin']);

};
```

For more info i recommend you read the documentation and familiarise yourself with the examples at http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

Comment: I have done exactly what you said and when I run the grunt I got a message:

C:\wamp\www\V2ThemeDevelopment\Gruntfile.js:7
                dest: '/app.min.css'
                ^^^^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: You have forgot to put , after src: ['templates/folder1/css/*.css'] ... Thank you.. it work as expected ! :)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, i've edited the answer to fix the code. If this answer helped you could you accept it?